# Using __call with static classes?

Tags: php, oop, static, magic-methods

Is it possible to use the `__call` magic method when calling functions statically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not yet, there is a proposed (now available) [`__callStatic`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/language.oop5.overloading#object.callstatic) method in the pipeline last I knew.  Otherwise `__call` and the other `__` magic methods are not available for use by anything but the instance of a object.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the *other* magic method, [`__callStatic`](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.overloading) - this is only available in PHP >= 5.3, which hasn't actually been released yet.

Comment: Import to note that's not available yet.

Comment: Ah bugger - I was wondering about this, and started to write the question... then I found __callStatic but didn't realise it won't be available until php 5.3

Comment: I haven't been as excited for a "minor" release in PHP since...Yeah PHP5.3 gives me hope for the language.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I would just like to point out that __callStatic is available >= 5.3  (Not > 5.3)   Not sure if anyone else was confused by that, but I was.

Answer (score 0):

As described before, there is no magic static caller. But you can code like this:

```
   class First {
        public static function test1(){
            return 1;
        }
        public static function test2(){
            return 2;
        }
    }


    class Second {
        public static function test1(){
            if(func_num_args()>0){
                return func_get_args();
            }
            return 21;
        }
        public static function test2(){
            return 22;
        }
    }

    class StaticFactory {
        public static function factory($class, $method){
            if(func_num_args()>2){
                $args = func_get_args();
                array_shift($args);
                array_shift($args);
                return call_user_func_array(array($class,$method), $args);
            }else{
            return call_user_func_array(array($class,$method), array());
            }
        }
    }

    print_r(StaticFactory::factory("Second", "test1", 1, false, true));

    print_r(StaticFactory::factory("First", "test1"));
```